# ROS2 compatible URDF for underwater robot (ROV)

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, ros-humble

I am looking for a urdf/ urdf skeleton for an underwater robot( or any robot that moves with thrusters instead of motors) and is ROS2 HUMBLE compatible. Doing my own URDF is a bit tricky so I want to build on top of an existing one. I have found UUV simulator, and Desistek Saga, but they're ROS1-compatible, while Plankton is similar, it is ROS2 ELOQUENT-compatible. If you haven't heard of anything as such, would you demonstrate how can I do my own urdf yet allow it to be controlled by BLUEROBOTICS T200 thrusters, because I can't get my head around it. While I need to publish tfs later in my project, I'm not sure how 'baselink' for example can be specified on an underwater robot.

Comment: Welcome at RSE. The URDF from ROS 1 itself should be compatible with ROS 2. What you are asking for is a complete simulation or localization setup? Please specify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not possible to give you one specific answer, I would suggest you, to create your own URDF robot file completely from scratch: [video](https://youtu.be/C8oK4uUmbRw?si=MBxyfr0o3VM2jKzG).

Then you can use as motor whatever you prefer. Remember, that ROS does not take care, if you "draw" a T200 thruster, a J73 turbine or a warp drive. What matters is the "value" associated to it. In your case the thrust generated by the engine. You can find those specific value in any datasheet.